# Cannot include .woff files into dist build directory when running tsc command

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, tsc, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I'm building a simple lambda function and i'm trying to include some statics font assets within the  compiled directory.

I have created a `.d.ts` file inside the project with the image file extension, and included it inside `tsconfig.json`. However, when I run the tsc command to build the project, the fonts are nowhere to be found...

My project structure

```
+ dist
  + lambda
    - helper.js
    - index.js
    - types.js
+ src
  + fonts
    - my-font.woff
    - my-font.woff2
  + types
    - fonts.d.ts
  - helper.ts
  - index.ts
  - types.ts
- .eslintrc.json
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
```

My `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2018",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "outDir": "dist/lambda",
        "removeComments": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*", "./src/**/*", "src/types", "src/types/fonts.d.ts"]
}
```

My `/.eslintrc` file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_" }]
    }
}
```

My `types/fonts.d.ts` file:

```
declare module "*.woff";
declare module "*.woff2";
```

I'm expecting my dist structure to look something like this:

```
+ dist
  + lambda
    + fonts
      - my-font.woff
      - my-font.woff2
    - helper.js
    - index.js
    - types.js
```

I've tried renaming my `fonts.d.ts` file, i've changed how i'm including files in `tsconfig.json` to every variation i can think of.
I've also tried different folder structures and filenames for the fonts themselves and varaitions or requiring and importing them in the index.ts file.

I've even tried adding `"types": "/fonts.d.ts"` to my `package.json` file

I've tried just about everything i can think of and everything i can find on google and i'm stumped... The worse part is i'm almost certain it's going to be something really obvious!